# Which Pi can emulate a custom USB Client?

Tags: gpio, usb, arduino, c++, pi-zero

Ok here is my problem: I'm making a product where I need to plug as a receipt printer and then I need to compute some data, read an NFC tag and send the data to a web server each time a receipt is send to the device.

I searched online about what device use as a base for my prototype phase (100 units maximum), because (1) due to time a custom PCB with custom spec is out of question, and (2) the Pi family is my best bet except I can't expect 100 Zero (which would be *perfect*).

So my question is in the Pi family which device could, with some hack, be a custom USB client who I could read data directly and do my little kitchen after?

From what I read elsewhere: Raspberry A could but nobody has a proof, GPIO on B+/2 could be done with some software hack (C++ should have a lib about that).

Other idea would be to use an Arduino chip, write it and solder it on a protoboard to interpret an USB Client and send data over SPI or UART.

1. I'm a software guy and before big production, we will see with someone for custom specs but not before we confirm the idea in a test phase.
2. Arduino: not enough horse power, CHIP: Awesome but not enough production (I asked), BeagleBone Black and Edison too expensive.

P.S. I'm not a native english speaker, so please excuse any errors. I would gladly correct them.

Answer (score -1):

Your request can be done via RPi A or Zero, see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41) and [this guide](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=699)

Comment: Thanks you, I will investigate the **g_printer** module and get my and on a Model A for testing.